# OpenSuse 13.2 - Sublime como editor padrão

Tags: linux, terminal, opensuse

Eu baixei o `sublimeText2` para edição de texto e gostaria de defini-lo como editor padrão em vez do `gedit` mas não estou conseguindo.

#### Tentativas

1. `Arquivo -> abrir com -> outro aplicativo -> visualizar todas as aplicações`
   contudo ele não aparece na listagem, creio que seja porque ele é baixado e executado, não instalado.
2. `Terminal -> su -> usr/share/applications/`

   - criar arquivo `sublime.desktop`
   - `vim defaults.list` substituir todos `gedit` para `sublime`
3. `Terminal -> su -> usr/share/applications/`

   - criar arquivo `sublime.desktop`
   - `vim mimeinfo.cache` substituir todos `gedit` para `sublime`

#### Conteudo sublime.desktop

```
[ktop Entry]
Name=Sublime
Comment=Sublime text Editor
Exec=sublime_text %U
Icon=sublime-dark-icon.gif
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=text/editor;
MimeType=text/plain;
```

#### Questão

Alguém saberia me disser o que estou fazendo de errado? e como resolver?

Comment: você tem que *necessariamente* usar a versão portável?

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira na verdade eu apenas entrei no site e acessei este link c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime%20Text%202.0.2%20x64.tar.bz2

Comment: eu tive um problema parecido no windows, e a culpa era da versao portavel. essa resposta me ajudou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450895/sublime-as-default-editor , mas é windows, né... não sei se te ajuda muito

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira valeu a tentativa, mas não ajuda, linux é bem diferente.

Comment: Coloquei uma recompensa p/ ver se mais alguém se interessa em ajudar

Comment: da p/ fazer uma gambiarra, renomear o gedit la no /usr/bin e colocar o sublime com o mesmo nome(renomeado) lá

Comment: Obrigado, @SneepSNinjA, esta mesmo pensando em por uma recompensa.

Comment: Eu estava pesquisando para criar ou definir o sublime como `application`, contudo as unicas referencias que encontrei comentavam sobre o `main menu` que eu já tenho, mas não aparece nas aplicações.

Comment: @SneepSNinjA eu voltei a fazer teste com os `.desktop` e consegui resolver estava faltando o `X-KDE-Protocols=Sublime` no arquivo, desta forma aparece no `Open with` da propriedades. Se você quiser postar uma resposta com esta solucao, marcarei como resolvido para você retomar seus pontos.

Comment: poste você mesmo a solução, pode marcar a sua própria resposta como aceita sem problemas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como contei no comentários com o @SneepSNinjA, encontrei a solução
realizando alguns testes nos `.desktop` em `usr/share/applications/`.

Notei que a única diferença entre os arquivos :

#### skype.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skype
Comment=Skype Internet Telephony
Exec=skype %U
Icon=skype.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/skype;
X-KDE-Protocols=skype
```

#### Sublime.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime
Comment=Sublime text Editor
Exec=sublime_text %U
Icon=sublime-text.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=text/editor;
MimeType=text/plain;
X-KDE-Protocols=sublime
```

Era a falta no `X-KDE-Protocols`, sendo que o `Skype` aparecia no `Open with` e o sublime não.

Desta forma apos editar o aquivo adicionando o `X-KDE-Protocols`, ele passou a aparecer no `Open with`. Depois foi só defini-lo como padrão.

### Update 27/02/2017

#### Processo

- 1º - Faça o download no sublime_text e extraia seu conteúdo.
  Digamos para `/home/user/bin/sublime_text`
- 2º - No terminal acesse a pasta do sublime e de permissão `+x` (execução) para `sublime_text`.
  `chmod +x /home/user/bin/sublime_text/sublime_text`
- 3º - Criar um link simbólico para `/usr/bin` (Note que isso vai afetar todos os usuário, e você deve ter permissão).
  `ln -s /home/user/bin/sublime_text/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime_text`
- 4º - Copiar o Icone do sublime para `/usr/share/pixmaps/`.
  `cp /home/user/bin/sublime_text/Icon/128x128/sublime-text.png /usr/share/pixmaps/sublime-text.png`
- 5º - Criar um `.desktop` em `/usr/share/applications/` (Como comentado a cima).
  OBS.: Isso serve apenas para criar um icone no menu.
- 6º - `alt+r` e executar comando `r`, se não funcionar talvez tenha que reiniciar.

Answer (score 1):

file.(txt|js|php..) > Properties > Open With > Sublime text 2 > Set as default

Answer (score 0):

faz um reconfigure assim

```
update-alternatives --config editor
```

ou coloca na mão no seu arquivo rc.local assim

```
export EDITOR=<caminho do seu editor ex:/usr/bin/pico>
```

Comment: no `update-alternatives --config editor` o sublime tambem não aparece na listagem do `--config`. Quanto ao `export `, criei assim `export Sublime=Programas/SublimeText2/sublime_text ` e deu ok, mas como implemento isto agora?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert no rc.local você coloca a linha "export EDITOR=/usr/bin/sublime" sem as aspas. Talvez tenha que trocar a palavra sublime por outra tenta autocompletar com TAB no shell para ver como aparece é desse jeito que aparecer no shell que tem que ficar no path do export

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert conseguiu resolver a questão ?

Comment: Não ainda não, no fim eu sempre abro arrastando o file, e deixei por assim, mas obrigado.